# CodeMirror does not prevent Ctrl+T to open a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, codemirror

I'm currently using `CodeMirror` and here is the code I have:

```
    cm.setOption("extraKeys", {
        'Ctrl-T':  function() {
            insertTitle();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The main idea is to execute the function `insertTitle` when the user presses `Ctrl+T`.

The issue is that, instead of executing this function, Chrome opens a new tab (default behaviour).

I tried to replace `Ctrl-T` by `Ctrl-A` but it didn't work.

I also tried with or without `return false` but it does not change anything.

Is there a way to prevent the Chrome default behavior ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not in English. You should translate your question to English.

Comment: Wow... Really sorry... I translated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not allow scripts to capture some keys. Ctrl-T appears to be one of them (Ctrl-N and Ctrl-W are others). There's nothing CodeMirror can do about this.

Comment: That's what I feared... OK then, thank you, I'll choose another shortcut :-p